# C++ Operator overloading styles, which is better for optimisation?

Tags: c++, optimization, operator-overloading

There are two ways to overload binary operators in C++: as a member function, or as a non-member function.

Since the Member function style can be included in the .h file, and the non-member style would be in the .cpp file, I would have thought that the member function style would make it easier for the compiler to optimise.

- Is there a difference in performance between member and non-member operators?
- Do member and non-member operators result in identical code (in any compiler)?

Comment: What do you mean "included in .h file and .cpp file"? For both case the declaration could be put in .h file, the definition could be put in .cpp file.

Comment: Non-member can be in the header as well iff it's `inline`. Member can be virtual.

Comment: If it's a non member I.e global, it could be included in  a .cpp or .h exactly the same if it is a member, .cpp or .h

Comment: Please correct me not I'm wrong, but I think the difference is near negligible from the perspective of jumping to the function in the asm code; with global, a directive could be used to alias the start of the instruction, and so jumping to the function would be "jmp func". However, if it is a member, indirect adressing is used of the [base + offset] form to locate the start of object then then offset to the function (perhaps this is only true for feilds not mem-funcs). Therefore you have one extra calc jmp [base + offset] for the indirect addition calculation

Comment: @izaak_pyzaak Member function address are not computed at run time (except for `virtual` in some sense), both will result in a single `call ...`.

Comment: So indirect adressing calculations will be precomputed at compile time?

Comment: @izaak_pyzaak There is no such thing as "indirect addressing" for member functions, you are confusing access to member functions and access to member variables.

Comment: Right, I was begining to think I was confusing the two in the large comment above. Thanks!

Comment: @songyuanyao - Wouldn't you get a linker error if the definition is in the .cpp, and the .h was included in two other .cpp files?

Comment: @Rocketmagnet You meant multiple definition error? No, it's fine, if you put only the declaration in .h file. And it's the common method.

Comment: @songyuanyao - Sorry, I mis-read your comment.  Anyway, I don't think my question has been answered. In the .h file, the compiler has access to all of the individual operations, and can inline them, and in some cases, e.g. where there is a mix of integer and floating point operations, interleave them in an optimal way to take full advantage of the FPU and any pipelines in the CPU. If the function is called, then the compiler has to treat it as a black box, and can't make the same optimisations.

Comment: @Rocketmagnet So you meant put the definitioin in header file? That's fine, for both member functions and non-member functions. I don't think there're differences for them.

Comment: If you really want to optimize something you can always use -O2 flag on gcc. P.S. Never use -O3 or -O4 they will kill your code...(speaking from personal experience: used it during a coding contest and it just erased my i++ in my for resulting in an infinite loop ---> too much optimization is bad :( )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I can say that the answer is yes, choosing member functions (with code in the .H file) or non-member functions (with code in the .CPP file) has some effect on the compiler's ability to optimise your code.

Here is a simple example. I have two operators here, one is a member function, and defined in the .H file. The other is a non-member function, and defined in the .CPP file.

First the class's .H file:

```
// test_class.h
// ------------
class Vector3D
{
public:
    Vector3D(double xx, double yy, double zz)
    : x(xx),
      y(yy),
      z(z)
    {}

    Vector3D operator +(Vector3D v)
    {
        return Vector3D(x+v.x, y+v.y, z+v.z);
    }

    friend Vector3D operator -(Vector3D v1, Vector3D v2);

    double  x,y,z;
};
```

Now the class's .CPP file

```
// test_class.cpp
#include "test_class.h"

Vector3D operator -(Vector3D v1, Vector3D v2)
{
    return Vector3D(v1.x-v2.x, v1.y-v2.y, v1.y-v2.y);
}
```

And finally, the main CPP file:

```
// ConsoleApplication1.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "test_class.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Vector3D a(1,2,3);
    Vector3D b(4,5,6);

    Vector3D c(0,0,0);
    Vector3D d(0,0,0);

    c = a+b;
    cout << c.x << c.y << c.z << endl;

    d = a-b;
    cout << d.x << d.y << d.z << endl;

    return c.x + d.x;
}
```

Looking at the assembler output, I can see that the member function produces fewer instructions than the member function:

```
; 20   :     c = a+b;
; 21   :     cout << c.x << c.y << c.z << endl;

push    DWORD PTR __imp_?endl@std@@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@....
movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR $T2[ebp+16]
movsd   xmm1, QWORD PTR __real@4014000000000000
mov ecx, DWORD PTR __imp_?cout@std@@3V?$basic_ostream@....
sub esp, 24                 ; 00000018H
movsd   QWORD PTR [esp+16], xmm0
movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR __real@401c000000000000
movsd   QWORD PTR [esp+8], xmm0
movsd   QWORD PTR [esp], xmm1
call    DWORD PTR __imp_??6?$basic_ostream@....
mov ecx, eax
call    DWORD PTR __imp_??6?$basic_ostream@....
mov ecx, eax
call    DWORD PTR __imp_??6?$basic_ostream@....
mov ecx, eax
call    DWORD PTR __imp_??6?$basic_ostream@....

; 22   : 
; 23   :     d = a-b;

movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR __real@4010000000000000
sub esp, 24                 ; 00000018H
mov eax, esp
sub esp, 24                 ; 00000018H
movq    QWORD PTR [eax], xmm0
movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR __real@4014000000000000
movq    QWORD PTR [eax+8], xmm0
movq    xmm0, QWORD PTR _b$[ebp+16]
movq    QWORD PTR [eax+16], xmm0
movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR __real@3ff0000000000000
mov eax, esp
movq    QWORD PTR [eax], xmm0
movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR __real@4000000000000000
movq    QWORD PTR [eax+8], xmm0
movq    xmm0, QWORD PTR _a$[ebp+16]
movq    QWORD PTR [eax+16], xmm0
lea eax, DWORD PTR $T1[ebp]
push    eax
call    ??G@YA?AVVector3D@@V0@0@Z       ; operator-
movq    xmm0, QWORD PTR [eax+16]
movq    xmm2, QWORD PTR [eax]
movq    xmm1, QWORD PTR [eax+8]

; 24   :     cout << d.x << d.y << d.z << endl;

mov ecx, DWORD PTR __imp_?cout@std@@3V?$basic_ostream@....
add esp, 52                 ; 00000034H
movsd   QWORD PTR _d$3$[ebp], xmm2
push    DWORD PTR __imp_?endl@std@@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@....
sub esp, 24                 ; 00000018H
movsd   QWORD PTR [esp+16], xmm0
movsd   QWORD PTR [esp+8], xmm1
movsd   QWORD PTR [esp], xmm2
call    DWORD PTR __imp_??6?$basic_ostream@....
mov ecx, eax
call    DWORD PTR __imp_??6?$basic_ostream@....
mov ecx, eax
call    DWORD PTR __imp_??6?$basic_ostream@....
mov ecx, eax
call    DWORD PTR __imp_??6?$basic_ostream@....
```

The member function and its cout produce 16 instructions, while the non-member function and its cout produce 37 instructions!

Why is this? This is because at compile time, the compiler only has the information available to it from the class's header file. It does not have the class's .CPP file available, and has to treat the member function like a black box.

In the member function example, the compiler inlines all of the function code, and sets to work optimising that. And in this case it can do a very good job because it can perform the arithmetic at compile time.

In the non-member function example, the compiler has to push the references to the arguments onto the stack, and actually perform the function call. And the result it gets back is a complete surprise.

However, if your toolchain supports whole program optimisation, then it may well be able to perform this optimisation later in the chain. If I turn on this type of optimisation, then the two functions produce the same number of instructions.

Answer (score 0):

The declaration as member or not member has nothing to do with optimization. The compiler is normally smart enough to produce equally optimized code in both cases if only that changes. And anyway, it would be low level optimization that only make sense for a precision compiler, version and configuration and can change for another one.

For a question of readability and maintanability, the operator should be member... unless it cannot. If it can, it allows to declare it inside the class definition which is coherent with OOP: it operates on objects of that class, let's try to make it a method on that class.

Simply there are cases where it is simply not possible. For example, output streams injector (`<<` operator) can accept second operands of any class, so it cannot be defined as member. That's the reason why C++ allows the non member definition of operators.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to declare the member and non-member versions of the overloaded binary operator like below, then they should be mostly equivalent:

```
struct A {
    A operator+(const A& other) const;     // 1
};

A operator+(const A& x, const A& y) const; // 2
```

One small difference may be that certain compilers may use a slightly more efficient [thiscall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#thiscall) calling convention for the member version (provided that they pass the `this` pointer through a register instead of pushing it on stack, and that they don't utilize the [fastcall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#fastcall) calling convention by default).

Another possible signature for a binary operator is to take the arguments by value:

```
A operator+(A x, A y) const;
```

However this declaration is possible only for the non-member version. The closest analogue of the member version would be this:

```
struct A {
    A operator+(A other) const;
};
```

which is equivalent to

```
A operator+(const A& x, A y) const;
```

Now, considering between passing by value or by (const) reference is not something that you can ignore. If you believe that passing by reference is unarguably more efficient, you are mistaken. Small classes with trivial constructor/destructor better be passed by value. In some cases, passing even somewhat larger classes by value can result in better optimization because it allows the compiler to forget about [**aliasing**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing_(computing)#Conflicts_with_optimization).